# How to present settings to the user in an iOS app?

Tags: android, ios, settings, preferences

For my current project I need to develop both an android and an iOS app. I never used iOS in private so I am not really sure about the best practices and how a user would expect my app to behave.

In android I provide the user with a custom view which offers different options (server IP, port, language settings, GUI settings, ...) which can be directly accessed by clicking the settings icon in the upper right border of my app. How would one do this in iOS?

What I've read by now is that there is the possibility to provide an settings bundle which will lead to an entry for my app in the system's settings app. But this means the user would have to leave my app to change his settings, right? I looked into a few standard iOS apps (Calendar, contacts, camera, ...) and it seems all apps use the settings bundle but there is no possibility to access this directly out of my app.

Would it be bad iOS practice if I offer a new view that can be accessed by the navigation bar and where the user can change those settings? How should I store them to be persistent over many app restarts? In Android I use the SharedPreferences object which is quite convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to store, you could store them in UserDefaults, or if it's something you need to store securely you could use Apple's KeyChain. Both of these will persist across launches and can be updated, appended to, or removed if needs be.

You can add a settings bundle as you've said and then in your app, you can hook a button up to present that settings screen to the user - so they wouldn't have to background your app, scroll to settings, find your app, etc., it'll be presented to them straight from your app.

Many apps also do their settings in the app, so it's really up to you - there is no hard and fast rule.

Comment: Linking the button to the settings app seems to be a good way. Do you know if it's possible to override the action that happens when the user leaves the settings app pressing the "settings" back button? It'd be great if the user could just open the settings app, change what he wants and then get back to my app by pressing the back button in the navigation bar

Comment: @ITStudent - Unfortunately that's not possible. However when the user is pushed out to the settings screen, in the top left corner of the status bar will be a back arrow followed by your name, and pressing this will return them to where they were before you sent them to the settings screen. :)

Comment: Nice, didn't notice that! I think that's good enough. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, if you're happy with the answer feel free to mark it as answered :)